# How can I remove field which are nil in CSV file

Tags: csv, logstash

My CSV file contains fields which are nil like that :

```
{ "message" => [
[0] "m_FRA-LIENSs-R2012-1;\r"
],
               "@version" => "1",
             "@timestamp" => "2015-05-24T13:51:14.735Z",
                   "host" => "debian",
           "SEXTANT_UUID" => "m_FRA-LIENSs-R2012-1",
"SEXTANT_ALTERNATE_TITLE" => nil
```

}

```
How can I remove all : messages and fields
```

Here is my CSV file

```
SEXTANT_UUID|SEXTANT_ALTERNATE_TITLE   
a1afd680-543c | ZONE_ENJEU  
4b80d9ad-e59d | ZICO   
800d640f-1f82 |
```

I want to delete the last line, I used filter ruby, but it doesn't work! It remove just the field not the entire message.

Comment: It is difficult to give a good answer without more information, but if you're on a Linux box, you might be able to use grep to strip out lines that have nil, or empty values.  Post a bit of the .csv file for better answers.

Comment: Do you mean you want to drop this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used if ([message]=~ "^;") { drop { } }   ans it's work => that for csv file

Answer (score 1):

If you configure your Ruby filter like this, it will work:

```
filter { 
    # let ruby check all fields of the event and remove any empty ones
    ruby {
        code => "event.to_hash.delete_if {|field, value| value.blank? }"
    }
}
```